# Feathers JS Client Timeout

Tags: javascript, client, feathersjs

I am sure this is something very simple, but for some reason I am getting a timeout when trying to integrate the feathersjs client with a very simple jQuery app.  Files of interest are in src below.  This repo only contains a single service "messages" connected to a NedB database with no authentication.  When the script starts, I am attempting to add a single message to my messages service.

Repo:

https://github.com/Ryan8765/jquery-chat

Error in Console:

```
Uncaught (in promise) Error: Timeout of 5000ms exceeded calling create on messages
    at client.js:66
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The server side application has been created with an old (v2) version of the CLI but you are loading @feathersjs/feathers@^3.0.0 in the browser which uses a Socket.io message format that is not supported by a v2 server.

`feathers --version` on the command line should show 3.3.0 or later. You can either follow the [migration guide](https://docs.feathersjs.com/migrating.html) to upgrade or install the latest `@feathersjs/cli` and regenerate the application.

Reference issue [feathersjs/feathers#761](https://github.com/feathersjs/feathers/issues/761).

Answer (score 0):

### I had the same issue using these package's on the client side with vue.js (`vue@^3.2.16` and `vite@2.6.4`)

- `@feathersjs/feathers@^4.5.11`
- `@feathersjs/socketio-client@^4.5.11`
- `socket.io-client@^2.3.1`
- `@feathersjs/authentication-client@^4.5.11`

My issue was resolved after changing

```js
import io from "socket.io-client";
```

to

```js
import io from "socket.io-client/dist/socket.io";
```

in my **client** feathersjs settings